# IContainerRegistryExtensions how to register an instance as singleton

Tags: xamarin.forms, prism

I am trying to migrate an old Prism Xamarin Form project to latest Prism and XF version.

I'd like to register a factory for creating connections like this `Func<SQLiteConnection>`:

```
public class AndroidInitializer : IPlatformInitializer
{
    string DbFilePath => Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Personal), "test.db3");

    public void RegisterTypes(IContainerRegistry container)
    {
        container.RegisterSingleton<Func<SQLiteConnection>>(() => new SQLiteConnection(DbFilePath));
    }
}
```

Howeve this doesn't work, there's no overload which takes an instance like I was used to do in old Prism Unity version.

Answer (score 0):

The ContainerRegistry is intentionally basic to handle the 90+% of registrations that you need in a consistent manner regardless of which container you're using. You can continue to use the underlying container for more advanced registrations.

For both DryIoc and Unity it would be:

```
containerRegistry.GetContainer().SomeContainerSpecificMethod();
```

where `SomeContainerSpecificMethod` would match what you had in Prism 6.3

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility is to use RegisterInstance to register a single instance of a class.  Not sure if this has implications for object lifetime though.

```
var connection = new SQLiteConnection(DbFilePath)
container.RegisterInstance(connection);
```